# Extract part of a string before and after a special character

Tags: php

I need to extract and show some words before and after a special character.

For example, this text: Anywords1 Anywords2 – Anywords3 Anywords4 (39948)

I need to show (PHP):

Anywords1 Anywords2

Anywords3 Anywords4

Many Thanks!

Comment: Please, take the [tour] and see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Going by your example you could use:

```
$re = '/([a-zA-Z ])+/m';
$str = 'Anywords Anywords – Anywords Anywords (39948)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```